# Python adding two dataframes based on index (edited)

Tags: python, pandas

(no idea how to introduce a matrix here for readability)
I have two dataframes obtained with Panda and Python.

```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['0','1','2'], 'number':[3,'dd',1], 'people':[3,'s',3]})
df1 = df1.set_index('Index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['0','1','2'], 'quantity':[3,2,'hi'], 'persons':[1,5,np.nan]})
```

I would like to sum the quantities of columns based on Index. Columns do not have the same name and may contain strings. (I have in fact 50 columns on each df).  I want to consider nan as 0. The result should look:
df3
Index     column 1      column 2
0           6            4
1           nan              nan
2           nan              nan

I was wondering how could this be done.
Note:
For sure a double while or for would do the trick, just not very elegant...

```
    indices=0
    columna=0
    while indices<len(df.index)-1:
         while columna<numbercolumns-1:
         df3.iloc[indices,columna]=df1.iloc[indices,columna] +df2.iloc[indices,columna] 
 indices += 1
 columna += 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try of concatenating both dataframes, then add based on the index group

```
df1.columns = df.columns
df1.people = pd.to_numeric(df1.people,errors='coerce')
pd.concat([df,df1]).groupby('Index').sum()
```

Out:

```
    number  people
Index       
A       8   5.0
B       2   2.0
C       2   5.0
F       3   3.0
```